# How to convert '1970-01-01T00:00Z' To Timestamp in gbq?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, timestamp

Java offsetdatetime returns '1970-01-01T00:00Z', which I am using in sql query to convert to IST timezone.

query :- select Date(cast('1970-01-01T00:00Z' as Timestamp),'Asia/Kolkata') as ist_date

error :- Invalid timestamp: '1970-01-01T00:00Z'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6gDx.png)

Comment: The way I read [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryParameterValue#com_google_cloud_bigquery_QueryParameterValue_date_java_lang_String_) you should pass a string in either `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` to BigQuery. Use for example `yourOffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))`. It gives you `1970-01-01 05:30:00.000000`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to parse the string first.

```sql
Select  parse_timestamp("%Y-%d-%mT%H:%MZ","1970-01-01T00:00Z",'Asia/Kolkata')
```